# Issue with linear animation

Tags: animation, processing

For some odd reason, the code below does not produce the desired effect. The sinewave is fine and functional, and the snippet of code below works perfectly, except for the movement forward, which is jolty.

I am using millis() and dividing by 1000 to convert to seconds, but the effect still produces what I would expect form using the second() function - the sinewave moving forward every 1 second. I want the lines to move horizontally smoothly, as the sinewave line does vertically. What have I done wrong?

```
int cyclesBeforeStopping = 4;
int distanceBeforeStopping = 400; 

float frequency = 0.2; // in Hz
float peak = 25; // Highest point of wave
float trough = 275; // Lowest point of wave
float amplitudeOffset;
float forwardOffset;

float timeUntilStop = (1 / frequency) * cyclesBeforeStopping;

void setup(){    
  size(600,300);
  frameRate(50);

  forwardOffset = ForwardOffset();
}

void draw(){  
  background(255);

  float forwardOffsetNow = forwardOffset * (millis() / 1000);

  // Guidelines
  line(50 + forwardOffsetNow, peak, 100 + forwardOffsetNow, peak);
  line(50 + forwardOffsetNow, trough, 100 + forwardOffsetNow, trough);

  // Sine line
  float newPosition = NewPosition();
  line(50 + forwardOffsetNow, newPosition, 100 + forwardOffsetNow, newPosition);
}

float ForwardOffset() {
  float forwardOffsetVar = (distanceBeforeStopping) / timeUntilStop;
  return forwardOffsetVar;
}

float NewPosition() {
  float omega = TWO_PI * frequency;
  float amplitude = trough - peak;
  float halfway = peak + amplitude / 2;

  float newPosition = halfway - (amplitude * sin(omega * millis() / 1000) / 2);

  return newPosition;
}
```

Comment: Turns out that `millis() / 1000 !== millis() * 0.001`. For whatever reason, dividing seems out output a floor rounded number to an integer, whereas multiplying does not round. This does answer my question, but I will not mark this question an answered until I know _why_ the calculations behave this way. If anybody knows why this happens, it would be really interesting to know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one dot solution :) just do:

```
float forwardOffsetNow = forwardOffset * (millis() / 1000.);//mind the dot after 1000
```

and also:

```
float newPosition = halfway - (amplitude * sin(omega * millis() / 1000.) / 2);
```

This is called integer division, well documented in Processing's wiki troubleshooting, [here](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Troubleshooting#Why_does_2_.2F_5_.3D_0_instead_of_0.4.3Fhttp://wiki.processing.org/w/Troubleshooting#Why_does_2_.2F_5_.3D_0_instead_of_0.4.3F).

It can be avoided by using a dot or an f after the number, like:

```
millis()/1000.;
```

or

```
millis()/1000.0;
```

or

```
millis()/1000f;
```

All will work.

Comment: A champion answer! Thank you so much